# MIPS Branching issue

Tags: assembly, mips, pcspim

I'm doing a project in MIPS; we could create anything we wanted as long as it employed certain requirements. Anyway, I chose to do a trivia program, which has been difficult but not impossible. Ran into a problem today with my branching.

```
incrEScore:

    add     $t9, $t9, 1             #increment incr. counter
    add     $t8, $t8, 1             #increment counter
    move    $v0, $t8                    #move to $v0

    beq     $v0, $s2, eQTwo         #counter=2, question 2
    beq     $v0, $s3, eQThree           #counter=3, question 3
    beq     $v0, $s4, eQFour            #counter=4, question 4
    beq     $v0, $s5, eQFive            #counter=5, question 5
    bgt     $v0, $t8, eTally            #counter>5, eTally

decrEScore:

    add     $a3, $a3, 1             #increment decr. counter
    add     $t8, $t8, 1             #increment counter
    move    $v0, $t8                    #move to $v0

    beq     $v0, $s2, eQTwo         #counter=2, question 2
    beq     $v0, $s3, eQThree           #counter=3, question 3
    beq     $v0, $s4, eQFour            #counter=4, question 4
    beq     $v0, $s5, eQFive            #counter=5, question 5
    bgt     $v0, $t8, eTally            #counter>5, eTally

eTally:

    beq     $t9, $s5, eWin          #if increment counter = 5, branch to Easy Win
    bltu    $a3, $s5, eLoss         #if decrement counter < 5, branch to Easy Loss
```

Variables initialized in my main:

```
    li  $s0, 0                      #init score
    li  $s1, 1                      #constant; menu num; answer num
    li  $s2, 2                      #constant; menu num; answer num
    li  $s3, 3                      #constant; menu num; answer num
    li  $s4, 4                      #constant; menu num; answer num
    li  $s5, 5                      #constant; counter compare point
    li  $s6, 6                      #constant
    li  $s7, 7                      #constant
    li  $t0, 8                      #constant
    li  $t1, 9                      #constant
    li  $t2, 10                 #constant; counter compare point
    li  $t3, 11                 #constant
    li  $t4, 12                 #constant
    li  $t5, 13                 #constant
    li  $t6, 14                 #constant
    li  $t7, 15                 #constant; counter compare point
    li  $t8, 0                      #question counter
    li  $t9, 0                      #increment counter
    li  $a3, 0                      #decrement counter
    li  $a1, 100                    #constant
```

Issue that is presenting itself is that instead of all the questions (those are the eQNums) running their course and the counter incrementing or decrementing fully, if at any time one question is wrong, the eTally will immediately branch off to a loss. This results in the rest of the questions being cut off/not run and the main menu popping back up. I tried doing a 'blt' instead of 'bltu' and I also tried using only the increment counter instead of both increment and decrement counters but found that none of these solves the problem.

Code is almost 1k lines so [here is a link to the full source code](https://github.com/kasieclark/catechism/blob/master/source).
Easy section is lines 165 to 299.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but did you account for the branch delay slot?

Comment: Use your simulator to step through the code and see where it goes wrong. There are a few very suspicious branches in there, such as line 240 and 252 will always be false since `v0` has been initialized from `t8`.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out with some help! Jester you were right- $t8 was initialized to 0 instead of 1 and it was throwing everything off!

Comment: And yeah, $s5 was supposed to be where $t8 was on lines 240 and 252.